# Swift: Implementing shortcutItem(3D touch) share item error "Value of type AppDelegate has no member of present"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I'm trying to implement share shortcutItem (my implementation):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "share"{
        self.shareItem()
    } 
}
func shareItem() {

    let visitedlink = "http://google.com"
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string: visitedlink)
    let img: UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!
    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }
    let shareItems:Array = [img,url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.mail]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But on this line:

```
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Value of type AppDelegate has no member of present
```

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The `AppDelegate` class is not a subclass of `UIViewController`. It doesn't have a `present` method.

Comment: @vadian : How can this be implemented on any viewcontroller ?

Comment: You need to get a reference to the current top view controller. The way depends on the implementation of the root view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
public extension UIViewController {
    func shareItem() {
        let visitedlink = "http://google.com"
        let myWebsite = NSURL(string: visitedlink)
        let img: UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!
        guard let url = myWebsite else {
            print("nothing found")
            return
        }
        let shareItems:Array = [img,url]
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.mail]

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```